# Two different HTML with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm in a condition where I've got a JSON file with all my data.
Those data are generating an HTML component of my code.

The issue is that, occasionally, the component code needs to change: in particular, a `<div>` has to become a `<a>`, due to the presence of a link.

The end result should be like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a b c">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="a b c">
    content
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="a b c">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

my data structure is something like this:

```
'element1':{
  'properties' = 'properties',
  'isLink' = 'true'
},
'element2':{
  'properties' = 'properties',
  'isLink' = 'false'
},
```

I am printing the `<div>` or the `<a>` with a loop of Angular, but can't find a clean way to tell the code something like "if 'isLink' = 'true' print an `<a>`, else print a `<div>`".

The closest solution I've found is this one below, which prints a useless `span` that breaks all the CSS:

```
<div class="container>
  <span ng-repeat="element in row.element">
    <div ng-if="element.isLink == false">
      content
    </div>
    <a ng-if="element.isLink == true">
      content
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Has anyone a solution to make it cleaner?
Thank you all.

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code of your attempt, and tell us what is wrong with it. If your question is about Angular, and not AngularJS, then change the tag of your question, too.

Comment: I've edited the post, hope it helps you understand better.

Comment: Can you add the css code and be more specific with your css breaking problem? Maybe we can find a solution there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-repeat-start="item in array" ng-if="!item.isLink">...</div>
  <a ng-repeat-end ng-if="item.isLink" href="#">...</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the parent span with a div element because divs have

```
display: block;
```

by default, while spans have

```
display: inline;
```

and probably that is why your css is breaking. Your html/angularjs code seems perfectly fine to me. Try to solve your css problem instead.

Comment: My css was breaking because the selectors are not finding di child to <div class="container>.

Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not the case.